# Using GIT in Salesforce

Tags: integration, git

I just tried to use GIT as our version control system. I went through following dreamforce tutorial by John Stevenson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P6ti5zQvRQ

I was able to create a GIT account and tried to unpack the Package that I had created in one of my sandboxes. 
The steps I followed were:

1. Add Force exe (from Force.com CLI for Windows) file in my GITHub repository.
2. After Force Login, I Tried to execute the following command to unpack the Package
   (force fetch -t=package -n=packagename -unpack)
3. Nothing happened and I kept getting the message 'Gonna do this again' in the command line

Please let me know if something is wrong with my steps.

Comment: Try using CumulusCI by Salesforce for Git integration. Read more about it (http://developer.salesforcefoundation.org/CumulusCI/ )